# How to save images with different names?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropdown

I'm dealing with a few issues regarding multiple images uploads. My project deals with a form the user inputs multiple images that save to a database, but first temporarily stores the images in a directory to show a preview of sorts. In my class, which deals with the uploading of the image I am trying to rename the images as seen below.

I uploaded seven images on the dropdown.

[image: dropdown]

I see that all its images were stored in the database by one.

[image: table]

While it had to be stored under different names.

Controller

```
public function store(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    $path = null;
    if ($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $name . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $file->storeAs($this->path, $fileName, 'public');
    }
    $gallery = Gallery::create([
        'product_id' => $product->id,
        'image' => $path,
    ]);
    return response()->json($gallery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = date('YmdHi');
    $extension = $name.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

> In controller , just replace it.

Comment: I see this in the database .   https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFnOe.png

Comment: 'image' => $path, change it to 'image' => $fileName

Comment: I want to save randomize in database

Comment: time().rand(100,999).$original_name;